# Error en instanciar objeto en java

Tags: java

Al momento de crear una instancia de un objeto con el código

```
Persona3 respuesta = new Persona3("","","",25,80,150f)
```

Saca un error diciendo: `String cannot converted to int` y toda la línea me aparece en rojo.

Comment: Villa24, Bienvenida a StackOverlflow. Sería de ayuda si incluyes la declaración del constructor de la clase Persona3. Sospecho que el error está en el último argumento, 150f, pero no tengo idea de qué tipo de dato es el que debes pasar, por lo que no se si sobra la "f", faltan las comillas, o es algo más.

Comment: era eso. muchas gracias jachguate

Comment: Excelente Villa, publicaré eso como respuesta para que puedas aceptarla.

Comment: Por favor provee el constructor de tu clase `Persona3`

Answer (score 1):

El error se encuentra en los argumentos que pasas al constructor de la clase

```
Persona3 respuesta = new Persona3("","","",25,80,150f) 
//                                                 ^
//    Esto no es un valor literal constante que    |
//    pueda ser reconocido por el compilador -------
//
```

el valor `150f` no es un entero, y tampoco es una cadena (si lo es debe estar encerrada en comillas dobles `"así como este ejemplo"` )

Dado que no se conoce la firma del constructor, no te puedo dar la solución, pero si lo que deseas enviar es un entero, quita la letra `f` que está de más, y si lo que quieres enviar es una cadena, no olvides encerrarla en comillas, así: `"150f"`.

Además, te hará falta un punto y coma `;` al final de la expresión.

Comment: @Luiggi, ¿por qué quitar el saludo?

Comment: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/182862), la 1ra y 2da respuestas más votadas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, @Luiggi, en realidad yo nunca lo he visto desde esa perspectiva. En los sitios en Inglés, no acostumbro dejar una línea como esa, pero creo que hay una diferencia cultural entre SO y es.SO. En todo caso quizás habría que discutirlo en el meta en Español.

Comment: Por favor crea la publicación en meta y vincula la pregunta que te pasé allí. Ahora, según tengo entendido, ese meta es para todos los sitios, no solo para un grupo de SO. Más bien, me parece que el checklist que se tiene está para palabras en inglés y no considera el español como *Hola*, *Buen(a)(os)(as) día(s)/tarde(s)/noche(s)", "Saludos", "Gracias" y demás. Pero de igual manera pienso que podría colocarse en nuestro meta y discutirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Sí la clase para instanciarla tienes que introducir de primero al tercer argumento "String" y del cuarto al Sexto argumento "Int", es lo que comenta el compañero que en el sexto argumento estas metiendo una cadena y no un entero

Answer (score 0):

Este problema no esta relacionado únicamente con NetBeans, el problema es que alguno de los valores que recibe tu clase `Persona3` esta definido para recibir un valor de tipo `int` y estas definiendo un valor de tipo `String` lo cual es incorrecto.

Revisa la implementaciòn de tu clase para asegurar que los valores son del tipo requerido para instanciar tu clase.